# Poisson PDE solver on a disked shaped domain with finite difference method using matlab

Tags: matlab, solver, pde, poisson

For my studies I had to write a PDE solver for the Poisson equation on a disc shaped domain using the finite difference method.
I already passed the Lab exercise. There is one issue in my code I couldn't fix. Function `fun1` with the boundary value problem `gun2` is somehow oscillating at the boundary. When I use `fun2` everything seems fine...

Both functions use at the boundary `gun2`. What is the problem?

[image: function 1 oscillating at the boundary]
[image: function 2 no oscillating]

```
function z = fun1(x,y)
    r = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
    z = zeros(size(x));
    if( r < 0.25)
        z = -10^8*exp(1./(r.^2-1/16)); 
    end   
end 

function z = fun2(x,y)
    z = 100*sin(2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*y);
end

function z = gun2(x,y)
   z = x.^2+y.^2;
end

function [u,A] = poisson2(funame,guname,M)

if nargin < 3
    M = 50;
end


%Mesh Grid Generation
h = 2/(M + 1);
x = -1:h:1;
y = -1:h:1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

CI = ((X.^2 +Y.^2) < 1);

%Boundary Elements
Sum= zeros(size(CI));

%Sum over the neighbours
for i = -1:1
    Sum = Sum + circshift(CI,[i,0]) + circshift(CI,[0,i]) ;
end

%if sum of neighbours larger 3 -> inner note!
CI = (Sum > 3);
%else boundary
CB = (Sum < 3 & Sum ~= 0);

Sum= zeros(size(CI));

%Sum over the boundary neighbour nodes....
for i = -1:1
   Sum = Sum + circshift(CB,[i,0]) + circshift(CB,[0,i]);
end

%If the sum is equal 2 -> Diagonal boundary
CB = CB + (Sum == 2 & CB == 0 & CI == 0);

%Converting X Y to polar coordinates
Phi = atan(Y./X);

%Converting Phi R back to cartesian coordinates, only at the boundarys
for j = 1:M+2
    for i = 1:M+2
        if (CB(i,j)~=0)
            if j > (M+2)/2
                sig = 1;
            else
                sig = -1;
            end
            X(i,j) = sig*1*cos(Phi(i,j));
            Y(i,j) = sig*1*sin(Phi(i,j));
        end
    end
end




 %Numberize the internal notes u1,u2,......,un

 CI = CI.*reshape(cumsum(CI(:)),size(CI));

 %Number of internal notes

 Ni = nnz(CI);


 f = zeros(Ni,1);

 k = 1;

 A = spalloc(Ni,Ni,5*Ni);



 %Create matix A!
 for j=2:M+1
    for i =2:M+1
        if(CI(i,j) ~= 0)
            hN = h;hS = h; hW = h; hE = h;

            f(k) = fun(X(i,j),Y(i,j));                                    
            if(CB(i+1,j) ~= 0)                                          
                hN = abs(1-sqrt(X(i,j)^2+Y(i,j)^2));
                f(k) = f(k) + gun(X(i,j),Y(i+1,j))*2/(hN^2+hN*h);
                A(k,CI(i-1,j)) = -2/(h^2+h*hN);
            else

                if(CB(i-1,j) ~= 0)  %in negative y is a boundry
                    hS = abs(1-sqrt(X(i,j)^2+Y(i,j)^2));
                    f(k) = f(k) + gun(X(i,j),Y(i-1,j))*2/(hS^2+h*hS);
                    A(k,CI(i+1,j)) = -2/(h^2+h*hS);
                else
                    A(k,CI(i-1,j)) = -1/h^2;
                    A(k,CI(i+1,j)) = -1/h^2;
                end
            end

            if(CB(i,j+1) ~= 0)                                          
                 hE = abs(1-sqrt(X(i,j)^2+Y(i,j)^2));
                 f(k) = f(k) + gun(X(i,j+1),Y(i,j))*2/(hE^2+hE*h);
                 A(k,CI(i,j-1)) = -2/(h^2+h*hE);
            else

                if(CB(i,j-1) ~= 0)
                     hW = abs(1-sqrt(X(i,j)^2+Y(i,j)^2));

                     f(k) = f(k) + gun(X(i,j-1),Y(i,j))*2/(hW^2+h*hW);
                     A(k,CI(i,j+1)) = -2/(h^2+h*hW);
                else
                     A(k,CI(i,j-1)) = -1/h^2;
                     A(k,CI(i,j+1)) = -1/h^2;
                end
            end

            A(k,k) = (2/(hE*hW)+2/(hN*hS));

            k = k + 1;
        end
    end
end

%Solve linear system
u = A\f;
U = zeros(M+2,M+2);
p = 1;

%re-arange u
for j = 1:M+2
    for i = 1:M+2
        if ( CI(i,j) ~= 0)
            U(i,j) = u(p);
            p = p+1;
        else
            if ( CB(i,j) ~= 0)
                U(i,j) = gun(X(i,j),Y(i,j));
            else
                U(i,j) = NaN;
            end
        end
    end
end


surf(X,Y,U);

end
```

Comment: Instead of dropping a bunch of code into your question, can you give a high-level explanation of what the problem is that you are solving (certainly defining the symbols that you use in the Poisson equation), and an overview of the solution procedure?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm keeping this answer short for now, but may extend when the question contains more info.*

My first guess is that what you are seeing is just numerical errors. Looking at the scales of the  two graphs, the peaks in the first graph are relatively small compared to the signal in the second graph. Maybe there is a similar issue in the second that is just not visible because the signal is much bigger. You could try to increase the number of nodes and observe what happens with the result.

You should always expect to see numerical errors in such simulations. It's only a matter of trying to get their magnitude as small as possible (or as small as needed).